# where is _generate_dropout_mask called in LSTM model

Tags: keras, keras-layer

### Context of Question

I am creating my own recurrent layer and wish to allow dropout, therefore I want to be able define the dropout masks in a way similar to the way LSTM does it.

I note they define the mask in a method.

### Question

When and where is the `keras.layers.recurrent.LSTMCell` method [_generate_dropout_mask](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1656) is called in order to create the member variable [dropout_mask](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1689)?

I've searched the github repository for `_generate_dropout_mask` in an attempt to see if it called somewhere, and cannot find its mention anywhere except in the `keras.layers.recurrent` module.

Is there a part of training that perhaps looks for all callable layer attributes with a single underscore prepended, and runs them before `keras.layer.build()`? Since dropout is only used for training, and since the masks must be available before building I suspect this, as this might allow layers to define prebuild methods using undrescore notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is a member of the class `SimpleRNNCell(Layer)`, [L659](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L659).

The cell is a member of the `SimpleRNN(RNN)` class, defined at the init method, and passed to the super class `RNN`. Follow the lines: L919, L933, L339, L357.

**The method is called inside the `call` method of a layer, L942.**

The call method is called literally when you [call](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py/#L526) a layer building your functional API Model. Not sure when the Sequential() model will call build. But it's certainly before, or at least immediately before, compiling. It's a phase that happens only once and links all the tensors together from input to output, creating the actual internal graph.

---

You can use `dir(instance)` to find all methods.
And you can use `getattr(instance,methodName)(...)` to call the method.

But `build()` is called before training. It's called when you call the layer for the first time when creating the graph with a functional API Model.

Comment: Sorry, I do not mean that I wish to be able to call it myself. I need to know when and where precisely it is called by `keras` during training, because I am creating my own recurrent layer and want to allow dropout. I will make that more explicit in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer if you download the tensorflow source code its in the recurrent.py file line 2248 to 2262 here is the code if you just want to make your your version of it

```
def _generate_dropout_ones(inputs, dims):
    return K.ones((array_ops.shape(inputs)[0], dims))


def _generate_dropout_mask(ones, rate, training=None, count=1):

    def dropped_inputs():
        return K.dropout(ones, rate)

    if count > 1:
        return [
        K.in_train_phase( 
         dropped_inputs, ones, 
         training=training)
         for _ in range(count)]
    return K.in_train_phase( 
       dropped_inputs, ones, 
       training=training)
```

It is called during the call method if the dropout is between 0 and 1 it then generates a mask of dropouts that is then applied to the input via

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops

def call(self,inputs,dropout=1):
    if dropout > 0 and dropout < 1:
        mask = _generate_dropout_mask(_generate_dropout_ones(inputs, array_ops.shape(inputs)[-1]),
        inputs *= mask
```